# Use ngIf with value from child component

Tags: angular, angular8

Using Angular 8 I have a parent component HTML:

```
<div>
  <p *ngIf="Condition with value$">Message</p>
  <child></child>
</div>
```

I need to use `ngIf` in `P` tag using `value$` that exists on Child Component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  value$: Observable<Model>;

  constructor(private service: service) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.value$ = // Get value using apiService

  }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use an `@Output()` to expose a value to the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Output` variable in child component to pass data to parent.

**child.component.ts** :

```
@Output() changeEvent = new EventEmitter<Model>();

ngOnInit() {
    // Once you subscribe the data from the service, emit an event passing data using event emitter
    this.changeEvent.emit(this.value$);
}
```

**parent.component.html** :

```
<div>
    <p *ngIf="Condition with value$">Message</p>
    <child (changeEvent)="onDataChange($event)"></child>
</div>
```

**parent.component.ts** :

```
// This function will be triggered when the child emits an event and the data will be available as parameter
// Use this data in your condition.
onDataChange(data){
    this.data = data;
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9mms62

Comment: But my variable is an Observable and its value taken using httpClient. How can I handle that? That is why I defined it as an Observable in my question.

Comment: @MiguelMoura That won't be a problem. Subscribe to the observable and emit event inside the subscription i.e. when you get the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  @ViewChild.
demo here: https://angular-zucwa1.stackblitz.io

parent .ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
 selector: "my-app",
 templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  @ViewChild("childComponent", { static: false }) childComponent: any;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

parent html file

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
parent component
<p *ngIf="childComponent.value$">
  show according to child value
</p>
<app-child #childComponent></app-child>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `EventEmitter, Output`

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihpsa2)

Parent Component:

```
<div>
  <p>Parent works</p>
  <p *ngIf="isMessageAvailable">Message depend on child</p>
  <app-child (isAvailable)="onChange($event)"></app-child>
</div>
```

Parent Class file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  isMessageAvailable: boolean = true;

  onChange(value) {
    this.isMessageAvailable = value;
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
<p>
child works!
</p>

<button (click)="valueChanged()">Toogle</button>
```

Class File:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Output() isAvailable = new EventEmitter();
  childValue: boolean = true;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  valueChanged() { 
    this.childValue = !this.childValue;
    this.isAvailable.emit(this.childValue);
  }

}
```

Comment: But my variable is an Observable and its value taken using httpClient. How can I handle that? That is why I defined it as an Observable in my question.

Comment: @MiguelMoura - it doesn't matter you can pass the value in event emitter

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve it:

1. As it was described earlier you can use @Output();
2. You can access a child component via @ViewChild()
3. You can write result from API in some property (ex. apiValue) in Service. Then you can inject service to both (parent and child) and track value of 'apiValue'. As Services are mostly singletons - you will get always the same instance with the same value. (It is more flexible way)

Comment: My first idea was to use a service but consider I have Parent1 > Child1 and Parent2 > Child2. Child1 needs to send value X to Parent1 and Child2 needs to send value Y to Parent2. Even if Child1 sets value X in service and Child2 sets value Y in service how to be sure that Parent1 gets the X value and Parent2 gets the Y value? Probably Parents would get the value that is in the service at the moment they access it and it could be X or Y depending on which Child defined the service value at the moment. Correct?

Comment: You could provide the service on Parent level (do not confuse with injecting). It will create separate instance for particular Parent and its children. And it would allow Parent 1 to get values emitted from Child1 and Parent2 from Child2 and keep them completely separate :)